# Node + Mongoose: Get last inserted ID?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, express, mongoose

I want to retrieve the last inserted `_id`, using mongoose as MongoDB wrapper for node.js. I've found the following tutorial, but I can't change any node modules because the app runs on a public server:

[Getting "Last Inserted ID" (hint - you have to hack Mongoose)](http://www.wonderlandlabs.com/wll_drupal/node/mongoose/insert_id.html)

Any other ideas? This what I want to do:

- Insert new user
- Get user's `_id` value
- Set a new session based on user's id
- Redirect to /

Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I'm using mongoose version 1.2.0 and as soon as I created a new instance of a mongoose model, the `_id` is already set.

```
coffee> u = new User()
[object Object]
coffee> u._id
4dd68fc449aaedd177000001
```

I also verified that after I call `u.save()` the `_id` remains the same. I verified via MongoHub that this is indeed the real ID saved into MongoDB.

Answer (score 5):

If you explicitly declare

```
    _id: Schema.ObjectId
```

for your model, then the ObjectId will not be available after new or save.
This is probably a bug.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to get the last inserted _id of a *sub object*, then create the object, and add it to the item.  Here's an example in NowJS using MongoDB and Mongoose (to add some schema sugar) which then converts the result to JSON to send back to the client:

```
                var nowRoomID = this.now.room;
                var Conversation = mongoose.model('Conversation');
                Conversation.findById(convID, function(error, conversation) {
                    var Blip = mongoose.model('Blip');
                    var createdBlip = new Blip();
                    createdBlip.author= nowUserName;
                    createdBlip.authorid = parsed.authorid;
                    createdBlip.body = revisedText;
                    createdBlip.created_at = new Date();
                    createdBlip.modified_at = new Date();

                    conversation.blips.push(createdBlip);
                    parsed._id = createdBlip._id;  //NOTE: ID ACCESSED HERE
                    message = JSON.stringify(parsed);

                    conversation.save(function (err) {
                        if (!err) {
                            console.log('Success - saved a blip onto a conversation!');
                            nowjs.getGroup(nowRoomID).now.receiveMessage(nowUserName, message);
                        }

                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB, if you don't explicitly set a document's `_id` value then the client driver will automatically set it to an [ObjectId](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs) value.  This is different from databases that might generate IDs on the server and need another query to retrieve it, like with SQL Server's [scope_identity()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) or MySQL's [last_insert_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

This allows you to insert data asynchronously because don't need to wait for the server to return an `_id` value before you continue.

So, as shown is Peter's answer, the `_id` is available before the document is saved to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I just get the id from the document passed to the callback, since save returns the saved document.

Answer (score -2):

Check below url

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html

you will find following code in given url

```
    var document = {name:"David", title:"About MongoDB"};
   collection.insert(document, {w: 1}, function(err, records){
  console.log("Record added as "+records[0]._id);
});
```

Comment: It's not **mongoose** solution