# Node.js & Mongoose, can't recover _id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to save a document in my collection and if the save is successful, return the _id of this same document. The problem is I get an undefined value to my _id in both case, either the created model from mongoose or from the callback return. Basically, my only way of getting the _id would be to search the document by one of its properties, and then get the value. This approach isnt what I want, knowing what im currently trying to do should work.

```
var createTrophy = new Trophy({
    name            : post.name,
    accessCode      : post.password,
    description     : post.description,
    members         : [id]  
  });

  Trophy.findOne({name:post.name}, function(err, trophy) {
    if(err){
      console.log('Mongoose: Error: ' + err);
      res.send('Error db query -> ' + err);
    }
    else if(trophy){
      console.log('Trophy ' + trophy.name + ' already existant');
      res.send('Trophy ' + trophy.name + ' already existant');
    }else{  
    createTrophy.save(function(err, doc){
      var uid = createTrophy._id;
      if (err) { 
        console.log('Error in trophy saving:' + err); 
        res.send('Error in trophy saving:' + err);
      }else{ 
        User.findOne({_id:post.id}, function(err, user) {
          if(err){
            console.log('Mongoose: Error: ' + err);
            res.send('Error db query -> ' + err);
          }
          else if(user){
            console.log(doc._id + ' ' + uid);
            user.trophyLink = doc._id;
            res.send(user);
            //user.save(function(err){
            //   if(err){res.send('Couldnt update trophy of profile');} 
            //});
          }
          else{
            console.log('User id Inexistant'); 
            res.send('User id Inexistant');
          }
        });
      }
    });
    }  
  });
});
```

The Schema

```
 var Trophy = new Schema({
        _id             : ObjectId,
        name            : String,
        accessCode      : String,
        description     : String,
        //reference to User ID
        members         : [Number],
        comments        :[Comment]
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have to supply `_id` in your Schema, it'll be generated automatically. and if you want the name to be unique you can also configure this in the Schema. if `members` are supposed to be "real" user _ids, than try sth like `[ObjectId]`.

```
var TrophySchema = new Schema({
  name: {type:String, required:true, unique:true},
  accessCode: String,
  description: String,
  //reference to User ID
  members: [ObjectId],
  comments: [Comment]
});
```

and i don't know if this works

```
var trophy = new Trophy({...data...});
```

like you did it, i always do it like this:

```
var trophy = new Trophy();
trophy.name = "my name";
// ...
```

and the `_id` should be set as soon as you create the object (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074245/node-mongoose-get-last-inserted-id).

so just do it this way:

```
trophy.save(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    if (err.toString().indexOf('duplicate key error index') !== -1) {
      // check for duplicate name error ...
    }
    else {
      // other errors
    }
    res.send('Error in trophy saving:' + err);
  }
  else {
    User.findOne({_id:post.id}, function(err2, user) {
      if (err2) {/* ... */}
      else if (user) {
        user.trophyLink = trophy._id;
        res.send(user);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

important is, that save doesn't return the trophy you have to use the one you created yourself.

Comment: This seemed to work. Not sure if its the err.toString() part that fixed the problem or the way you declare new objects or the modification to the schema, but thanks.

Comment: I can confirm that the way I declare the object solved it:
- when doing new Thing({}) the _id was undefined.
- when doing new Thing() and then setting its props, it worked.