# How to let the inserting to be synchronized, in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, synchronous

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Node + Mongoose: Get last inserted ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074245/node-mongoose-get-last-inserted-id)

I'm trying to insert a doc into mongodb by mongoose:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongo://localhost/shuzu_test');

var conn = mongoose.connection;

var user1;

conn.collection('users').insert({a: 111}, function(err, docs){
    console.log(docs);
    user1 = docs[0];
});

var question1;
conn.collection('questions').insert({
    t:'Hello', 
    userId: user1._id /*!!!! error: user1 is undefined */
}, function(err, docs){
    question1 = docs[0];
});
```

Please note this line:

```
/*!!!! error: user1 is undefined */
```

When it tried to insert questions, the `user1` is still not be inserted, it was still `undefined`. How to change to code to let the inserting to be synchronized? So I can make sure the `user1` have been inserted and have value before inserting questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your code that does the insert to the questions collection inside the callback from the insert to the users collection.

So like this:

```
conn.collection('users').insert({a: 111}, function(err, docs){
    console.log(docs);
    user1 = docs[0];

    var question1;
    conn.collection('questions').insert({
        t:'Hello', 
        userId: user1._id /*!!!! error: user1 is undefined */
    }, function(err, docs){
        question1 = docs[0];
    });
});
```